# Displaying enum values on Kendo DropDownListFor in Edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have an `enum` class and I bind its values to `Kendo DropDownListFor` in Create mode without any problem. In Edit mode, these values are bound to `Kendo DropDownListFor` as well, but the current value's index is not selected. I mean that the record's `IdentityType` is `Passport`, but `DropDownList` shows "Please Select" as in Create mode. How can I fix it?

**Note:** When using `@Html.DropDownListFor` instead of `Kendo().DropDownListFor` it works, but I want to perform this by using `Kendo().DropDownListFor`.

**Enum (IdentityType):**

```
public enum IdentityType
{       
    [Description("Identity Card")]
    IdentityCard= 1,
    [Description("Driver License")]
    DriverLicense= 2,
    [Description("Passport ")]
    Passport = 3
}
```

**Enum Helper Method:**

```
/// <summary>
/// For displaying enum descriptions instead of enum names on grid, ddl, etc.
/// </summary>
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue)
        where T : struct
{
    Type type = enumerationValue.GetType();
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("EnumerationValue must be of Enum type", "enumerationValue");
    }

    //Tries to find a DescriptionAttribute for a potential friendly name
    //for the enum
    MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString());
    if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            //Pull out the description value
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
    }
    //If we have no description attribute, just return the ToString of the enum
    return enumerationValue.ToString();
}
```

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.IdentityType)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-dropdown" })
    .OptionLabel("Please select").BindTo(Enum.GetValues(
        typeof(Enums.IdentityType)).Cast<Enums.IdentityType>()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.GetDescription(), Value = x.ToString() }))
)


//This works but I want to perform this by uisng Kendo().DropDownListFor:
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IdentityType, 
    new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Enums.IdentityType)), new { @class = "k-dropdown" }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem, and the only solution i found is to set manually value:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.IdentityType)
    ...
    .Value(Model.IdentityType.ToString())
)
```